# How to query many fields, allowing for NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails site that logs simple actions such as when people upvote and downvote information. For every new action, an `EventLog` is created.

What if the user changes his or her mind? I have an `after_create` callback that looks for complementary actions and deletes both if it finds a recent pair. For clarity, I mean that if a person upvotes something and soon cancels, both `event_logs` are deleted. What follows is my callback.

```
# Find duplicate events by searching nearly all the fields in the EventLog table
@duplicates = EventLog.where("user_id = ? AND event = ? AND project_id = ? AND ..., ).order("created_at DESC")

if @duplicates.size > 1
  @duplicates.limit(2).destroy_all
end
```

The above code doesn't quite work because if any of the fields happen to be nil, the query returns `[]`.

How can I write this code so it can handle null values, and/or is there a better way of doing this altogether?

Comment: Well it's just sql so you could add `user_id IS NULL OR user_id = ?` type syntax for each argument. Would this be appropriate to your case?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly,

some of the fields can be nil, and you want to find activity logs that have same user_id, same  project_id or project id can be nil.

So I guess this query should work for you.

```
ActivityLog.where(user_id: <some_id> AND activity: <complementary_id> AND :project_id.in => [<some_project_id>, nil] ....)
```

This way you would get the complementary event logs where user_id is same and project id may or may not be present

```
class ActivityLog
  QUERY_HASH = Proc.new{ {user_id: self.user_id, 
                         activity: complementary_id(self.id),
                         and so on....
  } }
```

Comment: In my case any combination of the fields could be blank as the record is saved - I can use your method for every field but it becomes quite long.

Comment: Then the problem is generating the query hash. You can store the query in a constant as a proc and then instance eval it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
# event_log.rb

def duplicate_attr_map
  {
    :user_id,
    :project_id
  }
end

def duplicates
  attribs = duplicate_attr_map.reject_if(&:blank?)

  query  = attribs.map { |attr| "#{attr} = ?" }.join(' AND ')
  values = attribs.map { |attr| self.send(attr) }

  EventLog.where(query, *values).order("created_at DESC")
end

def delete_duplicates(n)
  duplicates.limit(n).delete_all if duplicates.size > 1
end

# usage:
# EventLog.find(1).delete_duplicates(2)
```

*not tested, could be improved*